# How to flash/upgrade iBeacon to Eddystone?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I have a bunch of generic beacons from China that I'd like to upgrade to Eddystone. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Its always better if you say what you tried so far

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I have no solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some beacon hardware vendors like Estimote and Kontakt.io now support Eddystone™ too. You are able to easily change the broadcasting scheme of your beacon to iBeacon or Eddystone protocol. In the below video by [Pushmote URL](https://pushmote.com/eddystone-url), you can see how to change Estimote beacons' broadcasting scheme to Eddystone™ protocol:

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gX0AlAOB6NU](https://pushmote.com/eddystone-url)

As it's possible with Estimote and Kontakt.io beacons, it might be possible with yours too. Contact with your hardware manufacturer to see the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting it from [here](https://github.com/google/eddystone/issues/66)

> Generally the "transmit these bytes" instructions are carried out in
>   firmware on the beacon and can't be controlled in real-time via
>   software. Many beacon manufacturers have updated their provisioning
>   applications to allow their devices to broadcast Eddystone frames. For
>   generic beacons (maybe you mean raw BLE chips? or Arduino/R-Pi sets?)
>   you'll need to set the bytes to Tx manually since there's no generic
>   provisioning app (or not that I'm aware of).

Thanks to [Michael Ashbridge (aka) mashbridge](https://github.com/mashbridge)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you probably can't.   Generic beacons typically don't offer firmware upgrades, and few if any generic vendors offer Eddystone support.

Full disclosure: I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks, which sells beacons with Eddystone support.